# Importing a large XLSX or CSV to Phpmyadmin

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin, xlsx

I have this dataset from kaggle
the xlsx file is good but when i convert it to csv it becomes a little bit confusing
here is the xlsx file :
[XLSX database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrHex.png)
here is the csv file :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgYBK.png)
i would prefer to import the xlsx file cause the csv is displayed incorrectly
here's the error that i'm getting when im trying to import the csv file :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAOwX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRffZ.png)
i would prefer to import the xlsx file but i dont know how

I tried to configurate the max_execution_time to 0 and modify php.ini but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the screenshots the csv file looks ok. It's just that the column "description" contains long values which messes with the layout in Excel, but other than that it shouldn't really be a problem. But when importing the csv the error message is:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xammp...\ImportCsv.php on line 365.

Hard to say without extra info. How many rows does the XLSX have, or how many MB's is the csv file? My guess is the file is just too large, or maybe there is an error somewhere in the csv.

You could try Notepad++ and the [CSV Lint plug-in](https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint) to simply convert the csv file into an SQL script with `INSERT VALUES` and a `CREATE TABLE` statement with the appropriate column datatypes (based on the content of the csv data). It creates batches of 1000 inserts so it could run long time but shouldn't give an time-out. Alternatively you can use the plugin to check for any errors in the csv file.

Comment: the xlsx file have 23997 rows and 9 columns

Comment: indeed the column description contains long value, the problem is that the values ​​of the id column in the csv file are not the same as in the xlsx file